# Facebook login not working in CN1 javascript port

Tags: javascript, codenameone

I'm testing the javascript port and I'm wondering: Is social media login supported?.

At first, compilation failed with the following error in a CodenameOne component:

```
[ERROR] Method com.codename1.ui.html.HTMLComponent.<clinit>()V is claimed to be synchronous, but it is has invocations of asynchronous methods
    at com.codename1.ui.html.HTMLComponent.<clinit>
    at com.codename1.components.WebBrowser.<init>(WebBrowser.java:101)
    at com.codename1.io.Oauth2$2.<init>(Oauth2.java:254)
    at com.codename1.io.Oauth2.createLoginComponent(Oauth2.java:254)
    at com.codename1.io.Oauth2.showAuthentication(Oauth2.java:227)
    at com.codename1.social.Login.doLogin(Login.java:85)
    at com.myapp.utils.SocialMediaLoginHelper.doLogin(SocialMediaLoginHelper.java:316)
    at userclasses.StateMachine.onSignIn_ButtonFacebookAction(StateMachine.java:855)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.handleComponentAction(StateMachineBase.java:1371)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder$FormListener.actionPerformed(UIBuilder.java:2831)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1004)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
    at java.lang.Thread$1.run(TThread.java:68)
    at org.teavm.platform.Platform.launchThread(Platform.java:122)
```

Compilation succeeded after I defined the build hint `javascript.stopOnErrors=false` as suggested [here](http://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-javascript.html#troubleshooting). However, neither Google+ nor Facebook login works (infinite spinning flower). Interestingly, the only official CN1 demo I could find that features social media integration (facebook share or like) is the [Kitchen Sink demo](https://www.codenameone.com/demos/KitchenSink) and I experience the exact same problem there.

What is the problem? Is there any example of successful social media login using the javascript port?

PS: I ran the app using the preview html page generated by the CN1 build server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I recall this wasn't integrated into the JavaScript port. I'm guessing this should be easy, especially the share functionality where we can just use share links and some simple HTML.

I [filed an issue for this](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1713) although we probably won't be able to address it for the immediate milestone as we are knee deep in Windows support.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll watch the issue.

Comment: FacebookConnect seems to be implemented (see this closed Github [issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1713)). Any plans for Google+?

Comment: Is there an issue? Google effectively killed Google+ login replacing it with a new "google" login so we need to migrate that code anyway.

Comment: As at March this year when I asked this question, yes. I could neither log in via Facebook or Google+

Comment: Back then there was an issue for Facebook but not for Google. The code is rather different.

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look again and create a ticket if Google+ still doesn't work. Thanks